# Send data from two models to a view

Tags: node.js, express

I have a Category template and another Product. Preceded to return these models in a single view

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Category.find({}, function(error, data){
    // something 
  });

  Product.find({}, function(error, data){
    // something
  }); 

  res.render('produtos/index', { 
    categories: Categories,
    Products: Products
  });
});
```

Comment: using mongoose?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the object model libraries like Mongoose or Sequelize support Promises and probably you would be able to do something like this

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  const categoryPromise = Category.find({});

  const productPromise = Product.find({}); 

  Promise.all([
    categoryPromise,
    productPromise,
  ]).then(([
    products,
    categories
  ]) => {
    res.render('produtos/index', { 
      categories,
      products
    });
  })
});
```

Otherwise you'd be able to create your own promises like this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  const categoryPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Category.find({}, function(error, data){
      error ? reject(data) : resolve(data);
    });
  })


  const productPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Product.find({}, function(error, data){
      error ? reject(data) : resolve(data);
    });
  })

  Promise.all([
    categoryPromise,
    productPromise,
  ]).then(([
    products,
    categories
  ]) => {
    res.render('produtos/index', { 
      categories,
      products,
    });
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As **Mongoose** and **Sequelize** both support Promises.First you need to query all the categories and products and save it temporary in variable then before sending your response create and object and send it. Here is an example. I would prefer async/awit it makes your code more readability and saves you from `then()` chaining.

```
router.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
  let category, products;
  try {
    category = await Category.find({});
    products = await Product.find({});

    res.render('products/index', { 
    categories: category,
    Products: products

  });
  } catch (e) {
    return next(e)
  }


});
```

It also better, if you make **Repository** layer for querying your database. Also Use any design pattern for project structure

Answer (score 0):

Set mongoose's pormise to use es6 `Promise` like `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise`, then you can use `async/await` to query both model and render.

```
// note async
router.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
  let categories, product;
  try {
    category = await Category.find({});
    products = await Product.find({});
  } catch (e) {
    return next(e)
  }

  res.render('produtos/index', { 
    categories: categories,
    Products: products
  });
});
```